# VIM solarized color scheme looks wrong when using tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, gnome-terminal

I am trying to use the solarized color scheme in VIM using gnome terminal (Ubuntu).  When I run vim without tmux, it looks great, see below:

[image]

If I add the following commands to my .bashrc

```
# tmux configuration
tmux attach &> /dev/null

if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

and start the terminal with tmux, the colors do not look right, see below:

[image]

Here is the contents of the .tmux.conf file

```
source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings  /tmux/powerline.conf                    
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"                                                                                                                                          
set-option -g history-limit 10000
```

I am using https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized for the vim color scheme, and the terminal is: https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized.

EDIT:
With tmux:

```
~$ echo $TERM
screen
```

[image]

Without tmux:

```
~$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM` inside tmux? It should be `screen-256color`.

Comment: I added answer to original question edit.  My tmux does have the `set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` why is it screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of `$TERM` must be `screen-256color`, so that Vim correctly detects the availability of 256 colors. (`tmux` reuses the terminal definitions of `screen`, as this tool implements similar multiplexing.)

You either need to set the correct value for `TERM` inside tmux adding the line

```
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

to `~/.tmux.conf`, or force 256 colors in your `~/.vimrc` via `set t_Co=256` (which would be a workaround, and best guarded by `if $TERM == 'screen'` if you also use non-high color terminals).

Comment: Thank you, this is the problem, changing to screen-256color is a different question that I will ask.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was the tmux version 1.8.  I used advice from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940944/ugrade-tmux-from-1-8-to-1-9-on-ubuntu-14-04

Upgraded tmux to version 1.9a, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

Try tmux -2, the -2 means Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours.
I created an alias so that tmux always starts that way.

Comment: Thanks, also I did find a solution, just upgrade TMUX,  can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940944/ugrade-tmux-from-1-8-to-1-9-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: this was the only solution that worked on ubuntu 14.04.  i tried: upgrading to tmux 2, and adding set-option terminal-256color to ~/.tmux.conf

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with tmux and vim using solarized theme. 
The problem was solved with the help of this blog post: http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2012/10/17/vim-solarized-and-tmux/

My steps to solve this problem were:

1. Upgrade tmux to 2.0 version. (To see what your current version is use: `tmux -V`)
2. Add terminal support for 256 color mode (`~/.bashrc`):

   ```
   export TERM="screen-256color"
   alias tmux="tmux -2"
   ```
3. Tell tmux what terminal type should be used (`~/.tmux.conf`):

   ```
   set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
   ```
4. Force vim to use 256 colors (`~/.vimrc`):

   ```
   set t_Co=256                        " force vim to use 256 colors
   let g:solarized_termcolors=256      " use solarized 256 fallback
   ```

Restart terminal for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

### Vim

`~/.vimrc`:

```
set t_Co=256
colorscheme <name>
```

### Tmux

`~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

### Shell

After the previous changes, you should adapt your workflow to one of these options:

Option #1: always start tmux with the `-2` argument:

```
tmux -2
```

Option #2: set up an alias in your shell config file (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`):

```
alias tmux="tmux -2"
```

Option #3: create a `tmux` script in `/usr/local/bin/tmux` and make sure `/usr/local/bin/` comes before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/tmux -2 "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [Selenized](https://github.com/jan-warchol/selenized), which is a redesign of Solarized that uses standard color mapping, so such problems don't appear.
It also has slightly increased contrast and adjusted colors, resulting in better readability.