# How to set tmux terminfo to screen-256color?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

If I do not use tmux my terminal is the following:

```
~$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

If I use tmux by adding the following into .bashr

```
# tmux configuration
tmux attach &> /dev/null

if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

My `.tmux.conf` has a line `set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`, but the terminal is the following:

```
~$ echo $TERM
screen
```

This makes VIM ugly.  How can I get the tmux to use screen-256color?  Using gnome terminal on Ubuntu 14.02

Comment: I also use VIM inside tmux and my TERM environment variable is also set to `screen` by default. This does not affect the colors in VIM however; everything looks just fine. Do you have `set t_Co=256` inside your .vimrc? Also see [this page](http://robotsrule.us/vim) for more information.

Comment: I do have line in .vimrc `set t_Co=256`.  I am asking this question as an outcome of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201779/vim-solarized-color-scheme-looks-wrong-when-using-tmux/201793#201793.  Not sure why, but it messes up my VIM.

Comment: See [Getting 256 colors to work in tmux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux) and also [tmux, TERM and 256 colours support](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118806/tmux-term-and-256-colours-support)

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same problem (my `set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` seems useless).

So, whenever I need 256 colors, I use `tmux -2` to force it.

That ain't the solution, just a workaround.

Comment: Found the answer for my sistem, what version of tmux are you using?  `tmux -V`

Comment: @user1135541 thanks, I'm using `1.6`, maybe that's the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.02 uses tmux version 1.8, apperently it does not support screen-256color, so to resolve I followed this advice:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940944/ugrade-tmux-from-1-8-to-1-9-on-ubuntu-14-04

So:

```
~$ tmux -V
tmux 1.9a
~$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

And now everything works right.